# jQuery Validator: custom error message at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to get a custom error message based on a value set elsewhere on my page. I can incorporate that value into my validation logic, but I can't figure a way to have the message change. So what I need in the sample below is a way to change the "Phone number is invalid (International format accepted)" to a more appropriate message, based on the dailing code. So if dialing code is "+1" I want the message to be "Phone number is invalid (North American format accepted)."

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("jqphone", function (value, element, params) {
        value = value.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        var ddlName = "ddl" + element.id.slice(element.id.lastIndexOf("___")+3);
        var dialingCode = getDialingCode($("#" + ddlName).val());

        if(dialingCode == "+1") {
            return this.optional(element) || (value.match(... for NA);
        } else if(dialingCode == "+61") { //-- AU 
            return this.optional(element) || value.match(... for AU);
        } else if(dialingCode == "+64") { //-- NZ
            return this.optional(element) || value.match(... for NZ);
        } else { //-- all the rest
            return this.optional(element) || value.match(... for the rest);
        }
     }, "Phone number is invalid (International format accepted)");
});
```

Comment: The validator plugin supports one default message and one defined message per rule, multiple errors message for a single validation rule isn't supported natively afaik. You can however, hard-code the error label and edit its message inside the validation function.

Comment: couldn't you add a function instead of a string and store the message on the element using data, or in a hidden element?  For instance, instead of "phone num not valid", you could just have function(){return $(element).data('errormsg');}

Comment: @Chris that did it! In the messages section of the validator I added a function that looks at the dialing code and returns the appropriate message based on the dialing code